# How to trim title for mobile devices?

Tags: views, 8

I am working with Drupal 8 website, on my view I have a list of contents. Some titles are pretty long, what is fine for teh desktop view, but for mobile version I need to trim the tite up to 30 characters and display dots (...) in the end, is there a way to do it in Drupal Views Settings ?

Comment: Views doesn't know if it is displayed on a large or small screen. You should solve this with CSS instead: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/t/text-overflow/.

Comment: Yes - you can edit the field in the View and set it to a certain limit. But since you are talking about mobile, you need to use CSS and media queries. The results will not be predictable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I need to comment on the UX of the long titles. Is there some huge difference between your desktop and mobile users WRT the title length? If the longer titles are better for users then maybe they should be long on all devices. If there is not much lost by trimming them maybe they should be trimmed on desktops too, or simply rewritten to be shorter?

If it turns out it does make sense to have different title lengths on different browser widths you can do it by adding two Title fields in your Views, one regular with the full title, and the other trimmed:

- Rewrite results

  - Trim this field to a maximum number of characters
  - Trim only on a word boundary
  - Add "…" at the end of trimmed text

For *both* Title fields add a CSS class:

- Style settings

  - Customize field and label wrapper HTML

    - Create a CSS class

Name each class sensibly, so it's clear what they represent.

Then in your theme add the two CSS rules. Place the rule with the regular title class in the "general" part of your CSS (that usually applies to all, including narrow browser widths), and with it hide the field.

```
.mytitle--regular {
  display: none;
}
```

Place the override with both title classes inside the @media query that only applies to wider browser widths and hide it, for example, if you have a 30em breakpoint:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 30em) {
  .mytitle--trimmed {
    display: none;
  }

  .mytitle--regular {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

This will make sure that only the trimmed title is visible by default and only the regular for viewport/browser widths larger than 30em.

You can use [CSS Editor](https://www.drupal.org/project/css_editor) to adjust the CSS if you can't access your (sub)theme.